# How python reads the values from txt file by specific n characters

Tags: python

I have a text file with many values inside, and I want to read this file. The each value is 20 characters in length, e.g. -5.3815657119783E-04 with minus is 20 characters, and 3.4684258817593E-02 with one whitespace before 3 is also 20 characters in lengh.

Most of my data is connected together. Therefore, I want to read this file every 20 characters to form one value, which means I want to split the data by 20 characters used by python, then generate 1 D vector.

Here is the data file:

-3.2288090365673E-01 9.1882352987172E-02-3.6568412172092E-01
-1.6851899589453E-13-3.6952158259739E-06-1.7702955653531E-07
-1.3297325992783E-06-5.9693615642877E-04-3.8099426849223E-08
 3.4698984898706E-08-4.6509379769221E-12-2.2296405498928E-02
-5.2019999391601E-14-4.7969995006506E-08 5.6662120105254E-08
 8.9017338669484E-08-2.9332683813429E-06 1.0647933483993E-06
-6.7543843798968E-05-2.1529934384702E-03 2.2028879943185E-05
 1.1715465910941E+05-2.5234840649194E+05 1.2213290262328E+05
 6.1143067398521E-03 1.0479815336955E-04 7.8911962315577E-08
 7.2476042335761E-01 4.1208576787560E-03 0.0000000000000E+00
 5.3389720849081E-03 8.4526321374548E-05 4.8860066505864E-08
 7.1085208590414E-06 4.5249593432595E-01 4.1468076430511E-04
 5.6630655497271E-10 4.0969474876063E-11 9.7240386803972E-05
 6.5005706844622E-11 5.1549675717799E-04 8.1291425432847E-18
 3.4017603643097E-07 4.4928090110890E-03 1.8886378497020E-10
 6.2728934586839E-11 4.7522407515395E-08 3.3417538614997E-07
 1.9670991535049E-07 1.9522239039334E-08 2.7359845813293E-18

expected results:
-3.2288090365673E-01 
 9.1882352987172E-02
-3.6568412172092E-01
-1.6851899589453E-13
-3.6952158259739E-06
-1.7702955653531E-07
......

Comment: You forgot to include the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import numpy as np`

`n = 20`

`with open('20-characters.txt','r') as f:`

`mylist = []`

`for line in f:`

```
`for word in [line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]:`

  `mylist.append(word)`
```

`print(mylist)`

`mylist_new = filter(lambda a: a != '\n', mylist)`

`print(mylist_new)`

Answer (score 0):

The [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.readline) function takes an optional parameter for the max number of bytes to read:

```
numbers = []
with open("some_file.txt", "r") as f:
    while True:
        n = f.readline(20)    # Read 20 chars
        if not n: break       # EOF?
        if n.strip():
            numbers.append(float(n)) # Convert to float and add to list
```